# Two Dropdown Menus Displaying Same Content

Tags: jquery, html, drop-down-menu

I have two drop down menus displayed side by side. I am using a jQuery script where whatever is selected on drop-down,gets displayed on the drop-down button.I have a month and a year drop-down.

Problem: When I select a month, e.g. March, then March is displayed both on month and year drop-down buttons. Similarly if I select say year 2017, it gets displayed on month button as well instead of only showing on year button.

(I have attached the picture for reference).

[image]

Here's my Code:

```
<div class="row">

            <div class="btn-group">
                <button class="btn" id="month">Month</button>
                <button class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" style="background-color: transparent;">
                    <span class="caret"></span>
                </button>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu">
                   <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">January</a></li>
                   <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">February</a></li>
                    <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">March</a></li>
            </ul>
            </div>

            <div class="btn-group">
                <button class="btn" id="month">Year</button>
                <button class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" style="background-color: transparent;">
                    <span class="caret"></span>
                </button>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu">
                   <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">2017</a></li>



                </ul>
         </div>

    </div>
```

JQuery script:

```
   <script>

   $(function(){

    $(".dropdown-menu li a").click(function(){

      $(".btn:first-child").text($(this).text());
      $(".btn:first-child").val($(this).text());
    });

    }); </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Need to do it like below using `closest()` and `children()`:-

```js
$(function(){
    $(".dropdown-menu li a").click(function(){
      $(this).closest('.btn-group').children('button:first-child').text($(this).text());
      $(this).closest('.btn-group').children('button:first-child').val($(this).text());
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="btn-group">
    <button class="btn">Month</button>
    <button class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" style="background-color: transparent;">
    <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu">
    <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">January</a></li>
    <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">February</a></li>
    <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">March</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

  <div class="btn-group">
    <button class="btn">Year</button>
    <button class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" style="background-color: transparent;">
      <span class="caret"></span>
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu">
      <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">2017</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Note:- `id` need to be unique per element so either remove `id="month"` from button or provide unique id to both of them

Answer (score 1):

Using same Id for month and Year.

```
<button class="btn" id="month">Month</button>
 <button class="btn" id="month">Year</button>
```

Always remember to have unique id for each tag element. Change id and check again.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `.closest()` to get the closest parent `.btn-group`, and then `.find()` to get the first button.

```
$(function(){
    $(".dropdown-menu li a").click(function() {
        var button = $(this).closest(".btn-group").find(".btn:first-child");
        button.text($(this).text());
        button.val($(this).text());
    });
});
```